# POST request vue C#

Tags: c#, vue.js, http-post, postman, http-status-code-500

---EDITED QUESTION:---

I am building my very first website with c# web application as backend and Vue as frontend.
My GET and DELETE works fine, but when I want to run POST I get problems I cant fully understand how to fix..

According to my teacher my Axios connection looks fine and the problem is only in my backend..

What I think I am trying to do is to somehow bind the models so they speak to eachother?

My datamodel is Sale.cs and my viewmodel (from Vue) is called SaleVM.cs

Sale.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Models
{
    public class Sale
    {
        public enum Status
        {
            Started,
            Ongoing,
            Done,
            Removed
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; } //++
        [Required]
        public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; } //fk
        [Required]
        public string YourReference { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateSold { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateDone { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateEdited { get; set; }
        public Status StatusId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateDelivered { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SaleArticle> SaleArticles { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

    }
}
```

SaleVM:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Models
{
    public class SaleVM
    {
        public enum Status
        {
            Started,
            Ongoing,
            Done,
            Removed
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Reference { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateSold { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public Status StatusId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArticleRow> ArticleRows { get; set; }
        public virtual SelectedCustomer SelectedCustomer { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I think i have made them incorrectly because I have only guessed how to write them.

and lastly my SaleController:

```
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SaleController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public SaleController(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // POST: api/Sales/5
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Sale>> PostSale(SaleVM saleVM)
        {
          string customerNumber = (saleVM != null && saleVM.SelectedCustomer != null && Convert.ToInt32(saleVM.SelectedCustomer.CustomerNumber) > 0) ? saleVM.SelectedCustomer.CustomerNumber : "";

          List<SaleArticle> saleArticles = new List<SaleArticle>();
            if (saleVM != null && saleVM.ArticleRows != null && Convert.ToInt32(saleVM.ArticleRows) > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in saleVM.ArticleRows)
                {
                    saleArticles.Add(new SaleArticle()
                    {
                        ArticleNumber = item.ArticleNumber,
                        Price = item.SalesPrice,
                        Quantity = item.Quantity,
                        Description = item.Description,
                        Id = item.Name
                    });
                }
            }
            //foreach (var saleVM in SaleVM)
            //{
            Sale sale = new Sale();
            {
                sale.CustomerNumber = saleVM.SelectedCustomer.CustomerNumber;
                sale.YourReference = saleVM.Reference;
                sale.SaleArticles = saleArticles;
                sale.DateCreated = saleVM.DateCreated;
                sale.DateSold = saleVM.DateSold;
                sale.StatusId = (Sale.Status)saleVM.StatusId;
                sale.UserId = saleVM.UserId;
            };

            _context.Sales.Add(sale);
            //}

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetSale), new { id = saleVM.Id }, saleVM);
        }
    }
 }
```

I dont get any errormessages in visual studio, but when I try the code out in postman i get statuscode 500 Internal Server Error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at E37SalesApi.Controllers.SaleController.PostSale(SaleVM saleVM) in C:\Users\fadaka\source\repos\E37SalesApi\Controllers\SaleController.cs:line 47
> at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I do understand what it says, its just I cant really understand how to fix it and get my POST method to fully work.

I hope I am clear with my problem

I am very new to programming and find it very hard to find information online that is on a level that a noob like me can understand, especially when it comes to c# and vue working together.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. You're trying to access the property of an object that is null on line 47 of SaleController, probably saleVM or saleVM.SelectedCustomer is null

Comment: hello, thank you! I am writing the request like this: `{
    "customerNumber": "111",
    "userId": 2,
    "yourReference": "Referens namn",
    "dateSold": "2020-03-01T00:00:00",
    "dateCreated": "2020-03-01T00:00:00",
    "dateDone": "2020-03-01T00:00:00",
    "dateEdited": "2020-03-01T00:00:00",
    "statusId": 2,
    "dateDelivered": "2020-03-01T00:00:00"
}`

Comment: You should include your request JSON with formatting as part of your question as it's an important part

Comment: Add Frombody attribute, `PostSale([FromBody] SaleVM saleVM)`

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I would put a breakpoint on the first line of your PostSale action and check which parts of your model are null.

The properties in your JSON are supposed to match up with your model. UserId, StatusId, DateCreated and DateSold are fine but nothing else with get passed and therefore SelectedCustomer will be null (most likely causing your problem).

```
{ 
  "customerNumber": "111",
  "userId": 2,
  "yourReference": "Referens namn",
  "dateSold": "2020-03-01T00:00:00",
  "dateCreated": "2020-03-01T00:00:00",
  "dateDone": "2020-03-01T00:00:00",
  "dateEdited": "2020-03-01T00:00:00",
  "statusId": 2,
  "dateDelivered": "2020-03-01T00:00:00"
}
```

Should match up with below, i.e. there'

```
public class SaleVM
{
    public enum Status
    {
        Started,
        Ongoing,
        Done,
        Removed
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSold { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Status StatusId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ArticleRow> ArticleRows { get; set; }
    public virtual SelectedCustomer SelectedCustomer { get; set; }

}
```